# How can I create a 3D repeating pattern on top of a flat surface?

Tags: modeling

Consider:

[image]

I try to create a pattern and project with shrinkwrap on an object...But the main problem is after deleting a face from the target object I have too many vertices to connect. I try to create a 3D pattern on that shape.

Comment: hello, I think it's not clear, could you please reformulate?

Comment: i want add 3d pattern on face of object, isnt problem on cylinder or cube but on different shape i cant

Comment: so how did you do the one you show?

Comment: i create plane and make square grid after that use poke face, alt J and insert after that get pattern on plane... that cut the plane to make size perfect to fit shape of object...but problem is bridge that plane with object...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another solution is to use [*tissue add-on*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tissue.html#tissue)

1. Model your base shape:
   [image]
2. Create a component shape (the shape on top of final object)
   [image]
3. Select the *component object first*, and *then the base object*, and click *tessellate*.

*Note that the order in which you select the objects is important with tissue, if selection is done in the incorrect order you will up with strange results.*

[image]

4. Adjust options in redo panel <kbd>F9</kbd>

[image]

5. For this object, it was needed to *merge by distance* and extrude the bottom faces in `-Z`. This step may vary per object use case.
6. Also, can select border faces and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> *>Extrude Faces Along Normals* to create an extended border around the object.

---

Result:
[image]

Comment: looks great i will try thx

Comment: I was only looking for this kind of thing last week. Will the result be manifold so it can be 3D printed?

Comment: I would think so. Blender comes bundled with 3dPrint Toolbox to perform checks before export for printing.

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is create your plane, inset the faces, cut the shape with the *Knife Project* tool:

[image]

Inverse the selection, delete the faces:

[image]

Use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to select the areas, shift select the ones that it may miss:

[image]

Extrude up:

[image]

Switch to *Pivot Point > Individual*, scale down:

[image]

Now you just have to extrude the outer border to create the rest of the shape:

[image]

Comment: thanks man, u only reply on my 3 question and u help me a lot... i think about that what u suggest me but i wondering about more practical solution, if that is only way i will use that...thank again

Comment: Another solution is the Tissue addon, I'll try it and add to my answer if necessary. Edit: doesn't seem to work fine for this kind of case but you could give a try